# How to get the result of subtracting two timestamps in minutes?

Tags: php

I have this code to subtract two dates and get the difference between them in minutes:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Istanbul');
$date1 = '2014-07-01 09:07:25';
$date1 = date_create($date1);
$current_pc_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$current_pc_date = date_create($current_pc_date);
$diff = date_diff($current_pc_date,$date1);
$minutes_diff = $diff->format("%R%i");
echo $minutes_diff;

if($minutes_diff<5 && $minutes_diff>0)
{
    echo 'yes';
}
else
{
    echo 'no';
}
```

I want to subtract the dates and get the results in minutes but here it subtract the minute parts in the two dates so if I changed the hour part of the `$date` it still giving the same result when subtracting from the other date for example :

```
2014-07-01 02:25:48 
2014-07-01 02:23:48
```

it will result in `2 minutes`

if I changed the hour part it will still giving the same result :

```
2014-07-01 03:25:48 
2014-07-01 02:23:48
```

it will result in `2 minutes`

I want to have the result in the second example like `62 minutes`

Comment: `$minutes_diff = $diff->format("%h") + $diff->format("%i");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
function timeDiff($start_date,$end_date="now"){
    $time_diff = (new Datetime($start_date))->diff(new Datetime($end_date));
    $time_diff_minute = $time_diff->days * 24 * 60;
    $time_diff_minute += $time_diff->h * 60;
    $time_diff_minute += $time_diff->i;
    return $time_diff_minute;
}
    timeDiff('2014-07-01 03:25:48', '2014-07-01 02:23:48'); // 62
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just convert your times to seconds, then subtract, then convert the difference to minutes:

```
$t1 = '2014-07-01 03:25:48'; 
$t2 = '2014-07-01 02:23:48';

$minutes_diff = abs(strtotime($t1) - strtotime($t2)) / 60;

echo $minutes_diff; //62
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/f3PkmNfY)

---

References:

[**strtotime()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) converts the date to a timestamp (seconds since Jan 1 1970)

[**abs()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) gets the absolute value of the difference (in case `$t2` is greater than `$t1`)